# Looking for a (non-yellowy) white chalk pencil for marker illustration highlights

Tags: tool-selection, medium-selection

I am looking for a powdery, dry medium similar to a chalk pencil. However I notice that **not all chalk pencils are pure white and often exhibit a yellowy tinge.** I have seen "white charcoal" products advertised, but I believe these are a patented synthetic material?

**Background:**
I would like to add **pure white highlights** to studio marker illustrations, & charcoal illustrations on toned paper. I would like a non waxy/oily pencil that can be smudged/blended like charcoal. The last pencil I tried was a Stabilo Carbothello white chalk pencil.

Are there any pencils similar to chalk that are pure white?

Comment: Could you use a white soft pastel?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the Stabilo Carbothello Chalk-Pastel Pencil in Titanium White.[image]

I found one for sale on Amazon for $3.84, here: http://a.co/gimVlHQ

But, I'm sure you can find it in most office supply and/or art supply stores.

There are several other brands, but I would seek out those pencils labeled, "Titanium White" to prevent the yellow-ish tinge you refer to.

Titanium White is known for being bright white. If you're looking for a more transparent, but also clean white, try to find a "Zinc White."